# Matrices with almost constant coefficient have a simple eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, eigenvalues, eigenvector, operator-norms

As a by-product of a general result for bounded operators of a Banach space, I have the following:

> A matrix $L=(\ell_{ij})_{ij}$ that has almost constant coefficients in the sense that for some $c$, on all row $i$ it holds 
>   \begin{equation}
> \frac{1}{n}\sum_k \lvert \ell_{ik}-c\rvert\le \frac{|c|}{6},
> \label{eq:Perron}
> \end{equation}
>   must have a simple eigenvalue. Under a slightly stronger bound the eigenvalue is positive and so is its eigenvector probably.

My question is whether this is obvious in some way, or well-known.

This also made me wonder if there is a perturbation proof of the Perron-Frobenius Theorem: the matrix $J$ with all coefficient equal to $1$ has the dimension $n$ as a simple positive eigenvalue with positive eigenvector, and up to normalization the Perron-Frobenius theorem simply says that this property still holds true for matrices whose coefficients are less than $1$ away from those of $J$.

What made me wonder is that the above result is precisely obtained by applying a perturbation result to $J$.

Comment: This is remniscent of diagonal dominance for matrices

Comment: I don't think this is very obvious from the standard perturbation results: after normalizing (divide by $cn$), you have a perturbation of norm $<1/6$ in $\ell^{\infty}$, but your unperturbed matrix (which has eigenvalues $1,0$) is badly conditioned, with condition number $\sim \sqrt{n}$ in $\ell^{\infty}$, so that's not going anywhere. One has to use that the unperturbed matrix is specifically what it is.

Comment: I might have the constant wrong. I'll wait a more thorough check before editing, but it probably is $1/12$ instead of $1/6$, which probably don't change much the question.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: I am not surprised that such an approach does not yield the above: the general result (which I am currently checking) that I use to deduce this property holds in all Banach spaces and is thus quite dimension-insensitive. Under classical assumptions (e.g. normality) the only numerical quantity to be controlled is the norm of $(\lambda-L_0)^{-1}$ on the stable complement of the eigenvalue, which here with your normalization is $1$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: actually, it seems to me that the eigenvalue condition number is $1$ here (using the $\ell^\infty$ norm for vector and thus $\ell^1$ norm on covectors).

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner: By "condition number", I mean $\|A\| \|A^{-1}\|$, and this is $\sim\sqrt{n}$ if you use the norm induced by the $\ell^{\infty}$ norm both times.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: I didn't thought that condition number was relevant to eigenvalue estimation (while I understand its relevance to solving $Ax=b$); do you have a standard reference for these things?

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner: It becomes relevant if you want to use Gershgorin circle type estimates to general matrices (not diagonal dominant initially). Horn's book on matrix analysis has some material.